# Unable to work on mobile devices or browsers but on the emulate tool of intel xdk

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use the Intel XDK to develop applications.

---

I am just wondering what can be the reasons that these lines of code won't execute while running on web browsers or mobile devices? However they run just fine on the emulate tab. Of course, this is just a piece of code among other lines but I doubt the issue has something to do with this piece.

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnCheckPrice", function(evt)
        {
            var sFromAddress = document.getElementById('searchField').value;
            var sToAddress = document.getElementById('searchFieldTo').value;

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://ec2-54-77-1-36.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/webops/GetEstimate.aspx?distance=2&estimatedtime=5",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //$("#result").html(data);
                        //alert(data);
                        var datatest = "distance;2;time;5;price;190.90";
                        var arrResult = datatest.split(";");
                        //alert(arrResult[0].toUpperCase());
                        var sPrice = arrResult[5];
                        var sDistance = arrResult[1];
                        var sMinutes = arrResult[3];
                        document.getElementById('lblEstimatedPrice').innerHTML = 'Pris ' + sPrice + ' kr (' + sDistance + ' km, ' +sMinutes + ' minuters färd)';
                    }
                });

        });
```

Comment: I imagine the emulator is not running with the same security restrictions as a browser. You need to check the traffic (e.g. using a free tool like Fiddler2) and see if it is a cross-site or other security issue.

Comment: The piece of code is linked to a button, what happens is the button click event runs in the emulate tab, but when it comes to a real testing scenario it fails to trigger the event when the button is clicked. How would you go about fixing this issue? I can show you the rest of the code if necessary

Comment: If you can place it in a JSFiddle, I can test any tweaks from mobile as well as desktop here. Cheers.

Comment: Here it comes: http://jsfiddle.net/phillyobrian/4hWQw/
By the way, I did try to add the codes in the correct order but they don't seem to display correctly. There are something that I missed but I am not sure!

Comment: Can you pls provide me with at least some suggestions on how to fix this issue? @TrueBlueAussie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to make ajax requests(POST or GET) to a foreign website within Intel XDK or apps built by XDK, I recommend that you add the ***xhr.js*** script in the HEAD element.

For example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your New Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
        *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
        input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
        body { background-color:white; color:black }
    </style>
    <script src='intelxdk.js'></script>
    <script src='xhr.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* Intel native bridge is available */
        var onDeviceReady=function(){
        //hide splash screen
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
        };
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- content goes here-->
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

For more information about making ajax requests within Intel XDK, go to https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/how-to-access-JSON-data-in-HTML5-apps

Comment: This is actually the solution I am looking for. So simple and straight-forward. Thanks for your help @eashtianjr